# What sets the /sys/bus/usb/devices/xyz/power/control file?

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, attiny

## Long story short

I'd like to know if there's a way to control the value in the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1.1/power/control` file from a USB device descriptor. Host always sets it to `auto` and I'd like it to be implicitly set to `on`.

## Full story

I added a microcontroller to a laptop USB cooler because I wanted the device to sleep when the host is suspended. The microcontroller is a DigiSpark ATTiny85 and I'm using the [V-USB](https://github.com/obdev/v-usb) library to mimic a USB device.

To detect that the host is suspended, I'm constantly checking if the host sent a Start-of-Frame packet (which it does every 3ms or so, unless suspended) and if no new packets are received, the device goes to sleep. Receiving a SoF packet results in an interrupt which wakes the microcontroller and hence, the cooler.

So far, everything works perfectly.

However, I have a small issue with this file:
`/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1.1/power/control` which gets set to "auto" and, since there's really no communication between the cooler and host (apart from SoF packets that the host sends to device), the host autosuspends the device soon after it gets connected. :/

Once I set the file value to `on`, the host doesn't try to autosuspend the device anymore based on whether there's communication or not (the desired sleep on suspend behavior still works without a problem). But, of course, this needs to be done everytime the device is unplugged and plugged back in.

Now... maybe I could also send some dummy data from the cooler to host, to mimic communication, but, unless the host reads it, some buffer will definitely fill which is why this does not look like a solution.

I was wondering if there's some way to maybe tweak the USB device descriptor to tell the host that while this is a busPowered device, it should not try to autosuspend it.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this in case some lost soul runs into a similar thing.

So, I wanted to play around with WSL so I installed Windows 11. The device behaved in the same way, as in once connected it started but it got auto-suspended after a short time.

Initially I was using the default USB class from the [DigisparkCDC](https://github.com/digistump/DigistumpArduino/blob/master/digistump-avr/libraries/DigisparkCDC/usbconfig.h) library, but then decided to have a look at [DigisparkKeyboard](https://github.com/digistump/DigistumpArduino/blob/master/digistump-avr/libraries/DigisparkKeyboard/usbconfig.h) just for comparison.

While the former was connecting as a CDC device, the latter gets connected as a HID device. Changing the USB class was not enough though, as HID devices also pass some report.

After a lot of trial and error I got to a really minimal HID REPORT descriptor:

```
const PROGMEM char usbHidReportDescriptor[USB_CFG_HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH] = { /* USB report descriptor */
  0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
  0x09, 0x80,                    // USAGE (System Controller)
  0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
  0x05, 0x80,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (System Controller)
  0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Generic Desktop)
  0x75, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
  0x95, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
  0x81, 0x00,                    //   INPUT
  0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
};
```

This just needs to be pasted into ArduinoIDE as a global variable and the *usbconfig.h* file must be adjusted so that `USB_CFG_HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH` matches the length of the HID descriptor (and is also uncommented).

And that's it! It now all works as intended (on Windows), without getting autosuspended! This also seems to work fine on a different laptop with a Linux Mint 21 installation (for some reason it used to work on this one even before - why is beyond me - but there were some logs saying that reading the device descriptor failed).

**EDIT:** Seems like using `Undefined` for *Usage* and *UsagePage* causes intermittent issues with the device resuming when the host goes out of suspend. Replaced them with *Generic Desktop* and *System Controller* and it seems to work fine. Feel free to experiment if you run into issues!

Answer (score 0):

For that matter, you don't even have to disconnect/reconnect a device for it to re-set the values.  On my Fedora 36 system, it's shutting off the keyboard and mouse a few times every work day.  And it isn't like i haven't been using them, sometimes it shuts them of in the middle of typing something.

Something must be actively changing the settings back, as I'll see the keyboard lights flashing whenever the connection dies.  I have to wait a minute until it decides to start working again.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this, though. It sometimes takes a week or two in between reboots on my laptop, and unless that happens or I disconnected the cooler, it will keep behaving as expected. Any of the actions above resets that file though...